# HTML & PHP | Filling a select with a query

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a function that uses mysqli function that is as follows:

```
public function GetProjectOptions()
{
    $return = "";
    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `project_name` FROM `projects`;";
    $rs  = static::$link->query($sql);
    $return .= '<select class="form-control" name="project">';
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs));
    {
        $return .= "<option value='" . $result['id'] . "'>" . 
                    $result['project_name'] . "</option>";
    }
    $return .= '</select>';
    return $return;
}
```

The purpose of this function is to create the options and select that will be used for the Projects on my site, I know that there are 4 projects currently stored in the table, but they do not return in this function, what have I done wrong?

EDIT:

```
Link to screen output: (http://i.imgur.com/YIYiheH.png)  
Link to code output: (http://i.imgur.com/RZsUIwQ.png)  
Link to code usage: (http://i.imgur.com/4J9rvd7.png)
```

(Wouldn't let me do normal links)

Comment: You haven't used any error checking.

Comment: The error checking is done in the construct function

Comment: How can your constructor check that query for errors?

Comment: I thought he meant on the `$link`... My mistake, the server that a I am using (WampServer) let's me know if there is an error and prints this to me

Comment: @JayBlanchard, the `$sql = "...;"; is there so the SQL statement knows where the query ends and the second is for PHP

Comment: @Styphon, I have tested all queries before putting them into this function on my server, I can say with 100% confidence that these statements are correct

Comment: @SamSwift: When you debug this, where specifically does it fail?  What is the exact output?  What are the results of the SQL query?

Comment: You're going to have to go check your error logs. There is nothing that we can see in the code that you've posted.

Comment: @David It doesn't fail at all, it throws no errors or messages, it just does not go into the `while` clause, I have debugged with `exit`s throughout the function and the only place it didn't exit was in the `while` clause

Comment: @SamSwift: What *does* it do, though?  Is the `select` tag successfully built?  If you output the count of records returned by the query, what is that count?

Comment: @David, The select is built, the HTML and PHP processes the script and runs through, I cannot count the items, nor can I print the `$result` variable

Comment: @David, upon inspection of the code at runtime, the select option comes through as such: `<select class="form-control" name="project"><option value=''></option></select>`

Comment: probably a variable scope issue. pass the db connection to the function

Comment: The DB connection cannot be passed, it is held in a private static variable for security

Comment: @Fred-ii-, the `static::$link` variable is declared in the scope of the class it is used in

Comment: got it. ok, well since you're using name attribute, we're assuming that you're using a form for this or passing it as a POST/GET array somewhere. all I see is a return, but we don't know if you're echoing anything. your question is unclear at this point. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. also http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  on your query

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I have added links to images of code, output and debugging, does this help?

Comment: not really. we need to see if you are getting "errors"

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I have added the error reporting as you suggested to, there were no errors produced in the code, nothing in debug etc

Comment: I found the problem. Consult my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem.

Remove the semi-colon here

```
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs));
                                         ^
```

that's why it's not throwing an error, because it's considered as valid syntax.

Your loop is being stopped/terminated by it.

Comment: *Me too Ralph* We should start calling you Eagle-Eye @Fred -ii-

Comment: It's always the simplest mistake baking the biggest problem, thank you so much, seriously, you've saved me hours of trouble!

Comment: *Golly Sam*, when everything added up but didn't add up, I took an even closer look at it, then BAM!! @JayBlanchard

Comment: @SamSwift I know Sam. btw, the "Sam" thing with Jay, it's not aimed at you lol - we've got this "Ralph & Sam" Loonie Tunes thing happening. Glad this got solved, *cheers!*

Comment: @SamSwift oh and you're very much welcome Sam. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

What I think Jay and Styphon mean by their comment is that you don't do any error checking within your SELECT query.  Are you sure your query is executing properly? I understand this is a relatively simple query and that you're positive there are four projects currently stored in your table, but it's always a good habit to check.  Try this:

```
public function GetProjectOptions()
{
    $return = "";
    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `project_name` FROM `projects`;";
    $rs  = static::$link->query($sql);
    $return .= '<select class="form-control" name="project">';
    if($rs){
        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs));
        {
            $return .= "<option value='" . $result['id'] . "'>" . $result['project_name'] . "</option>";
        }
        $return .= '</select>';
    }else{
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error() . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $sql;
        die($message);
    }

    return $return;
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: if it's a variable scope issue, the error checking won't appear. I'm not saying this answer is wrong, am just stating what could be the or an issue. plus `mysqli_error()` requires DB connection be passed as a parameter http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php `string mysqli_error ( mysqli $link )`